# cypress-cucumber-preprocessor to connect both testing frameworks doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cucumber, cypress

I want to connect Cypress and Cucumber and I found the following plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

But my implementation does not work and cannot be found. I also added the plugin into the `plugins/index.js` folder.

cypess/integration/test.feature

```
Feature: Background Section

   Background:
    Given counter has been reset

   Scenario: Basic example #1
     When counter is incremented
     Then counter equals 1

   Scenario: Basic example #2
     When counter is incremented
     When counter is incremented
     Then counter equals 2
```

cypess/integration/test.js

```
let counter = 0;

Given("counter has been reset", () => {
  counter = 0;
});

When("counter is incremented", () => {
  counter += 1;
});

Then("counter equals {int}", value => {
  expect(counter).to.equal(value);
});
```

cypess/plugins/index.js

```
// Cucumber Plugin
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
}
```

Error

[image]

Comment: Made it work myself. See jogelin answer at `https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/issues/126`

Answer (score 0):

You must to configure path to step_definitions, if you want to customize it.

But if you prefer the easy way, by default cypress-cucumber-preprocessor uses the folder ***cypress/support/step_definitions***

So I believe that if you move your test.js file to the folder described above, will solve your problem.